# Implementar 2 critérios de busca na query (Wodpress/MySQL)

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress

Dentro dessa consulta como faço para adicionar mais 2 critérios de busca `$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_viewable'` e `$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'yes'`?

```
$query10 = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users ON($wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts ON($wpdb->posts.post_author = $wpdb->users.ID)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'noo_resume'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_job_category'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%{$key->term_id}%'
    AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn'
    AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'value_1'
");
```

Estou tentando mas está retornando um array vazio, mesmo tendo dados cadastrados no BD respeitando esses critérios da busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que você esta buscando campos conflitantes na tabela `post_meta`. Nessa tabela um registro não pode ter duas `meta_keys` ao mesmo tempo, então você precisa de uma expressão `OR` pra buscar ambos os valores separadamente, algo assim:

```
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'noo_resume'
AND ( 
  ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_job_category' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%{$key->term_id}%' )
  OR
  ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_viewable' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'yes' )
)
AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn'
AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'value_1'
```

Assim a query vai trazer da tabela `postmeta` tanto as linhas com meta_key `job_category` quanto as que tem meta_key `_viewable`